# why is the serverless framework rust plugin failling in dockerless and dockerised build mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am currently building my rust lambda using the dockerless method, it builds and deploys fine but when I attempt to test it throws the error:

```
Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: no such file or directory Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

I then tried building it using a builder image following [this](https://github.com/softprops/lambda-rust/issues/86) method but that when it ran it returned the error

```
/var/task/bootstrap: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /var/task/bootstrap)
```

The image used for the build is

```
FROM lambci/lambda:20200812-build-provided.al2

ARG RUST_VERSION=1.51.0
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs \
    | CARGO_HOME=/cargo RUSTUP_HOME=/rustup sh -s -- -y --profile minimal --default-toolchain $RUST_VERSION
ADD build.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 777 -R /usr/local
VOLUME ["/code"]
WORKDIR /code
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/build.sh"]
```

Which does have an version of glibc higher that 2.18

At this point I am out of ideas as to what to try next and would really appreciate it if some one could give me any ideas that allow me to deploy my rust lambda functions using the serverless framework

P.s I did originally try using the plugin with it's defaults but its to far out of date to be usefull

Comment: This question being very specific to problems related to the current state of a particular library, it would probably be more relevant on that project's issue tracker.

Comment: I have also put it on the projects issue tracker [here](https://github.com/softprops/serverless-rust/issues/98) but given the rate of response to issues I was wondering if any one here could provide a quicker answer, there is also another issue that is similar and also unanswered [here](https://github.com/softprops/serverless-rust/issues/97)